# Does R. Avraham Ben HaRambam really hold that only one child is necessary for peru u'revu?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, pru-urvu

There is a dispute between Beit Shammai and Beit Hillel as to what constitutes a fulfillment of the commandment to "be fruitful and multiply" (peru u'revu).

[**Yevamot 61b**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=61b&format=pdf)

> מתני' לא יבטל אדם מפריה ורביה אלא א"כ יש לו בנים ב"ש אומרים שני זכרים
>   וב"ה אומרים זכר ונקבה שנאמר זכר ונקבה בראם
>
> MISHNAH. A MAN SHALL NOT ABSTAIN FROM THE PERFORMANCE OF THE DUTY OF
>   THE PROPAGATION OF THE RACE UNLESS HE ALREADY HAS CHILDREN. [AS TO
>   THE NUMBER]. BETH SHAMMAI RULED: TWO MALES, AND BETH HILLEL RULED:
>   MALE AND A FEMALE, FOR IT IS STATED IN SCRIPTURE, MALE AND FEMALE
>   CREATED HE THEM. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Yevamoth.pdf); capitals in original)

The law is codified by [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in accordance with Beit Hillel:

**[Hilchot Ishut 15:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=99957&rid=3148)**

> כמה בנים יהיו לאיש ותתקיים מצוה זו בידו זכר ונקבה שנאמר זכר ונקבה בראם
>   היה הבן סריס או שהיתה הבת אילונית לא קיים מצוה זו
>
> How many children is it necessary for a man to have fathered to be
>   considered to have fulfilled this mitzvah? One boy and one girl, as
>   [implied by Genesis 5:2]: "He created them, a male and a female." If
>   the son was a saris or the daughter an aylonit, he is not considered
>   to have fulfilled this mitzvah. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952889/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Fifteen.htm))

[R. Avraham Ben HaRambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Moses_ben_Maimon) [has a responsum in which he clarifies his father's view about the mitzvah of marriage](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93620/13438). In this responsum he distinguishes between the mitzvah of marriage and the mitzvah of peru u'revu. Defining the latter, he writes:

**[Birchat Avraham # 44](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43006&st=&pgnum=77)**

> ומצות פריה ורביה מצוה אחרת היא שמצות פריה ורביה כשיהיה לו בן או בת
>   קיים המצוה
>
> And the commandment of being fruitful and multiplying is a separate
>   commandment; [regarding] the commandment of being fruitful and
>   multiplying, once he has a son or a daughter he has fulfilled the
>   commandment.

This is somewhat surprising, as R. Avraham appears to state that the commandment is fulfilled with just one child, boy or girl. This follows neither tannaic view, and is against the ruling of his father.

[R. Moshe Meiselman writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Meiselman):

**Torah Chazal and Science p. 87**

> In Rabbeinu Avraham's case, by contrast, we almost never find him
>   disagreeing with his father on halachic issues in his published
>   writings.

How are we to explain this statement of R. Avraham? Does he actually hold that only one child is necessary, against both views in the Mishnah and against the codification of his father? Was he simply being imprecise in his description of the mitzvah? Do any subsequent authorities deal with this puzzling passage?

My own intuition was that there might have been a typo/scribal error, and the words בן או בת really were בן ובת (i.e. an extra א was added) with the original meaning "a son **and** a daughter". Indeed I found one contemporary sefer that just casually said:

> נ' דצ"ל בן ובת
>
> It appears that it should say "a son and a daughter".

But I don't have any manuscript evidence for this.

Comment: Doesn't the Netziv also quote an opinion (or hold?) that pru urvu is fulfilled (at least Deorayta?) with one child?

Comment: "I don't have any manuscript evidence for this." Was this teshuvah written in Hebrew or translated from Arabic? Do we have the Arabic original?

Comment: @wfb Apparently Hebrew.

Comment: אפי' לרבנן דמצות פו"ר הוא זכר ונקיבה מכ"מ מודו דעיקר מצוה סגי בולד א' וכמש"כ בשאילתא י"ח אות ב' דעת רבינו דנשא אשה ולא ילדה כלל אינו רשאי לבטל אבל אם יש לו ולד א' שוב אינו מוציא. It's (unsurprisingly) in his commentary to the Sheilta about Pru uRvu (#165) and he references back to #18 about divorce if you don't have kids

Comment: Tosefta Yevamot 8:3 has a Tannaitic opinion of a single child sufficing (also in bYev 62a).

Answer (score 6):

While he does not make any connection to the view of R. Avraham, [R. Yosef Qafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) cites a view of [R. Sa'adia Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon) that also considers the commandment to only require one child (at least nowadays).

**Commentary to Hilchot Ishut Chapter 15 Note 10**

> וכתב מבשר הבבלי בשם רס"ג דמה שבא בתורה שבע"פ דקיום מצות פריה ורביה
>   בשני בנים או בן ובת דוקא באותן הדורות שהיו ימיהם ארוכים אבל עתה באחד
>   מהם בלבד זכר או נקבה ע"כ ראה פירושי רס"ג לתורה מהדורתי בראשית ד יב
>   ואיני יודע יסוד לדעה זו והשוה רס"ג בסוף ספרו האמו"ד המאמר העשירי פ"ט
>
> And the *Mevaser Habavli* wrote in the name of R. Sa'adia Gaon that
>   that which comes in the Oral Law that the fulfillment of the
>   commandment of being fruitful and multiplying is with two sons or a
>   son and a daughter, was specifically in those generations where their
>   lives were long. But now, with one of them alone – a male or female –
>   [it is enough to fulfill the commandment], end quote. See the
>   Commentary of R. Sa'adia Gaon to the Torah, my edition, Genesis 4:12.
>   And I don't know any foundation for this view. Cf. R. Sa'adia Gaon at
>   the end of his book *Emunot V'deiot* Essay 10 Chapter 9.

I found a contemporary sefer that actually used this question as a proof to his theory about the nature of the commandment of peru u'revu. R. Dovid Metzger argues that when we say that the commandment is to have a boy and a girl it does not mean that if you only have one child you have not fulfilled the commandment. Rather, every child born is a fulfillment of the commandment; the only question is about how much you are obligated to fulfill the commandment. Beit Shammai holds that you are obligated to continue until you have two sons, and Beit Hillel holds that you are obligated to continue until you have a son and a daughter.

R. Metzger argues that this is the implication of various formulations of the law, particularly the formulation in the Mishnah. The Mishnah says that one should not abstain from the commandment unless he already has children. That implies that each child is a fulfillment of the commandment, but there is an obligation to continue fulfilling the commandment until a certain threshold is reached.

R. Metzger then cites R. Avraham Ben Harambam as proof to this idea. If this idea is not true, then R. Avraham is flatly rejecting both opinions in the Mishnah, which is inconceivable. Therefore, it must be that R. Avraham is just saying that the commandment is **fulfilled** by having one child, but of course one is still obligated to further fulfill the commandment and have more children until he reaches the threshold mentioned in the Mishnah.

Thus, according to R. Metzger, R. Avraham's formulation is not a mistake; it is in fact very precise, and it is in full agreement with the Mishnah and subsequent codifications of the law.

**Daliyos Dovid Siman 21**

> ונראה שלענין קיום המצוה לית מאן דפליג דלכו"ע קיים מצות פר"ו בין בב'
>   זכרים ובין בזכר ונקבה ואף בב' נקבות ויתירה מזו אפי' בבן אחד או בבת אחת
>   נתקיימה מצות פר"ו וכל המחלוקת היא ממתי רשאי אדם ליבטל ממצוה זו ואינו
>   חייב יותר מן התורה להתעסק במצוה זו שהרי כך מורה לשון המשנה ביבמות שם
>   לא יבטל אדם מפריה ורביה אא"כ יש לו בנים וכו' וכן בגמ' שם האי יש לו
>   בנים מפריה ורביה בטיל וכו' הרי שלא כתוב כאן שעור במצות פר"ו שיהיה לו
>   ב' בנים אלא כתוב עד מתי אדם מחוייב במצוה זו ואינו רשאי ליבטל ממנה
>
> וכן מורה לשון הרשב"א בתשו' ח"ג סי' שלט לא אמרו במשנתינו שלא יבטל מפריה
>   ורביה אא"כ יש לו בנים אלא יתעסק עד שיהיו לו שני זכרים לב"ש וכו' וכן
>   מורה לשון תלמידו בספר החינוך מצוה א וז"ל דיני המצוה וכו' וכמה בנים
>   יהיו לו ויפטר וכו' הרי שלא כתב וכמה בנים יהיו לו ויקיים מצוה זו אלא
>   ויפטר להורות שיש שיעור לחיוב אבל לא לקיום דהקיום הוא בכל בן או בת שאדם
>   מוליד
>
> והנה מצאתי בספר ברכת אברהם לרבינו אברהם בן הרמב"ם סי' מד שמשמע להדיא
>   כן (דן שם בנוסח הרמב"ם בענין כסף מדברי סופרים ר' לעיל פ"א) וז"ל שמצות
>   פריה ורביה כשיהיה לו בן או בת קיים המצוה ולכאורה דבריו מרפסין איגרי
>   שהרי משנה מפורשת ביבמות סא ב דלכו"ע לא סגי באחד דבעינן שנים אולם להנ"ל
>   אין כאן שום סתירה שכונת הדברים שקיום מצות פר"ו יש בכל בן ובת שמולידים
>   ושעור החיוב שחייב במצוה זו עד כמה בנים או בנות שיש לו מחויב עדיין
>   לקיים מצוה זו בזה עוסקת המשנה
>
> ולפי"ז יש לבאר גם את לשון הרמב"ם כמה בנים יהיו לאיש ותתקיים מצוה זו
>   בידו שכונתו לומר שיותר אינו מחויב במצוה זו ותו לא אבל אין כונתו לומר
>   שבבן אחד או בת אחת לא קיים מצוה זו וגם בסברא לא יתכן לומר שמי שיש לו
>   עשרה בנים או עשר בנות לא קיים מצוה זו ומי שיש לו בן ובת קיים אלא ברור
>   שאין ספק שלגבי קיום המצוה כולם קיימוה וזה שיש לו עשרה בנים או עשר בנות
>   קיים עשר פעמים מצות פר"ו אלא שעדיין הוא מחויב במצוה זו ואינו רשאי
>   ליבטל ממנה והדבר מוכרח בסברא וכי התורה מצוה אדם על דבר שאינו תלוי בו
>   אם הולד זכר או נקבה והרי זה תלוי בקב"ה לבדו