# Is Nisuin Biblical or Rabbinic?

Tags: marriage

In exploring the topic of a [convert or orphan who is married as a Na'arah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101438/9682), I stumbled upon a surprising piece in the [Beis Shmuel](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.37.27):

> ...הואיל קידושין דאורייתא הם ונישואין אינם מדאורייתא...
>
> ...since Kiddushin is from the Torah, but Nisuin is not from the Torah...

While it's obvious that Kiddushin is from the Torah, I was surprised to see an opinion that Nisuin is *not* from the Torah, as I had never heard of such a thing before. Indeed, it's the Rambam's opinion that Kiddushin and Nisuin are two parts of the same Biblical mitzvah (as discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93616/9682)).

1. What is the Beis Shmuel's source for this assertion?
2. Whatever the answer to #1, how does the Rambam address it?

Comment: Is this then two questions?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Yes, but it's two heavily related questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Beis Shmuel does not mean to say that in general *nisuin* is Rabbinical. He is referring to the Mordechai which the Rema on which he is commenting refers to, which explains that since the father is dead, the *nisuin* *in this case* is Rabbinical, while the *kiddushin* performed before the father died is Biblical. Language of the Mordechai, [תקטז](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37962&st=&pgnum=361):

> כי אמרו אפילו ישאנה בעודה קטנה כיון שקידושיה  היו קידושין דאורייתא ונשואין דרבנן **דליכא אב למימסר לחופה** הרי היא כביאת זנות...
>
> [Some Rabbis] said that even if he marries her while she is still a minor, since the *kiddushin* was Biblical and the *nissuin* Rabbinical, **as there is no father to transfer her to the chuppah**, it will be like *zenus*...